# Ionic Storage and variable

Tags: javascript, angular, variables, ionic-framework, promise

Hello I want to assign returned value from promise to external variable.
I tried many times but finally I give up.

```
  export class TestPage {
  test:any;

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {

    storage.get('testy').then((value) => {
        this.test = value;
    });

  }


  }
```

Comment: How do you know you've failed? Where do you display/use `this.test`?

Comment: it displays undefined if i put outside .then

Comment: check the place where ur trying to store the value

Comment: When i use console.log of value in storage it works. But i want to asign this value to external variable.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike component properties, instance variables of Dependency Injection should also be accessed using `this`

```
this.storage.get('testy').then((value) => {
            this.test = value;
 });
```

Comment: still, the result is the same :/

Comment: Did you print value? What do you get? And you cannot print/access it outside then callback. You always get undefined.. since it is an asynchronous call.

Comment: Thats the problem, I need to give value from callback to external variable so i can use in other place.

Comment: What external variable are you referring? `test` is it?. You are doing it right there, Assigning to global component variable is perfect. What is the problem? You can access it anywhere now.

Comment: Yes to variable called test. Looks good, not working. In html page i tried to show it and then error, undefined

Comment: Ah! Your html is rendered before the component has loaded the data from storage.Give a condition before you use that in your template `<div *ngIf="test">{{test}}</div>`

Comment: Hmmm, now page loads, but my variable test is still empty, in .then statement it shows in console.log but outside it doesnt.

Comment: Strange! Show your template file please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the storage outside the constructor and check

```
export class TestPage {
test:any;

constructor(private storage: Storage) {}
this.storage.get('testy').then((value) => {
    console.log('Testvalue is', value);
    this.test = value;
});   


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the value of storage before load page with ionViewWillEnter event:

```
export class TestPage {
   test:any;

   constructor(private storage: Storage) {}
   ionViewWillEnter(){
        this.storage.get('testy').then((value) => {
        console.log('Testvalue is', value);
        this.test = value;
      });          
   }
}
```

Comment: still i get the undefined error :/